# Sql listview Button Function

Tags: android, listview, row, android-sqlite

hi I am beginning  android developer in android. I have developed in TODO training app Now i have one doubt in how to delete button inside in the listview row item please help me.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please Elaborate more.

Comment: list view inside in the delete button function@SoftCoder

Comment: you want to delete button inside the list view ? or you want to delete an item in listview through delete buttom ?

Comment: yes i want to delete button inside the list view @SoftCoder

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Button button;
button = (Button)this.findViewById (R.id.yourbuttonid );
//***
button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```